# Can I connect to database with another language

Tags: c#, database, security, communication, between

Hi i have a C# WinForms app. I wrote essential methods on C#. But I need a login form and its not safe since apps like dotpeek can inspect the source code and hack it. Can i communicate with another application that is written in another language (java,c,python etc). I need to send input data from WinForms C# to another app then it should connect to database and check if login succesfull then return a value back to C# WinForms app. Is that possible, how can i implement that? I dont want to write all application in another language since C# has good methods to process images/pixels and gui support with very small memory usage.

Comment: You want to use another language because you're concerned about someone using a tool to inspect the running code? Guess what....that can happen to all languages!

Comment: This is why you shouldn´t save security-relevant information in source-code. In fact there´s little chance to completely hinder anyone to decompile your program, be it written in Java,C# or even C++, not to mention all the scripting-languages.

Comment: I want to use an external app because my database id,password etc all visible when its written in C# why do you vote down that question?

Comment: The key here is not about the **language**, as **all** of them have the same "problem". The key is not to store passwords in source-code. Anway I did not vote at all.

Comment: You can communicate with "any" application using http or tcp/ip transport for example. That other app can be written in C# also. See client–server model

Comment: Guys is hosting a PHP page like an API that connects to database then returns some boolean or JSON to C# app, more safe and OK to use on a commercial project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the point you are trying to make.
One thing to admit is that you can't completely avoid decompiling of apps. C# or C++, no matter anything can be reverse engineered.

If you still need it, a comparatively safer approach is to not put the checking app at the client's machine. Create an API and host the database on a server.
Then initiate just an Http Request to the server from your Windows Forms app.

Then you have the full control of Login API and database. Many applications use OAuth similar to this. Another examples are apps verify it's license using an online API.

You can get a LightSail Windows server in around $10 a month if you want to setup. Try exploring

Comment: This is the only correct answer. Apps running on client machines should not be directly connecting to a database. They should be talking to an API that runs on a server, and that API can connect to the database on the user's behalf.

Comment: @mason Perhaps so, but this will not solve all of the security issues. (Not that I know of a way to do that. Just pointing that out.) Threats from the web host, or anybody compromising the web service, and someone impersonating the app to get whatever information the app can get (by decompiling the app), which OP seems to be worried about. (Besides the fact that this answer doesn't answer the actual question. But I know many here don't care about that, "XY problem" and all...)

Comment: What we can accomplish is to make the reverse engineering harder. There are ways to obfuscate the exe file. They will make it tougher to decompile. Another way is to store a checksum of the original application under on API server. Then on every request the original app need to send it's checksum on header. Recompiling a reverse engineered code won't match with the original version checksum (like a signature) at server, so it fails to bind on endpoints, This is just another approach I heard off

Comment: @ispiro Of course it won't solve all security issues, but removing direct database access from client apps is absolutely something that should be done if you want to consider your system secure. Clients are not given access to the web hosting servers themselves, thus an attacker must break through another (much harder) layer of defense. Impersonating the app to get information isn't a big deal - because the API is responsible for authorizing all user requests to make sure that clients can't do anything they're not supposed to.

Comment: Can i create my own API by hosting PHP

Comment: Sure. If you are creating an API, language doesn't matter. Since PHP and C# will exchange data in JSON or XML format. There are language independent

Comment: @Sangeethnandakumar Your checksum idea would only be a very minor roadbump, especially for someone with the expertise to decompile the app already. They can just grab a checksum of the original app, then harcode the decompiled app to always provide that checksum. You can't control what clients do, which is why all authorization checks need to happen on the server side.

Answer (score -1):

Your concern is *not* baseless. C#, or for that matter, any .net language running on the CLR, *will* be easier to inspect than a language like C or C++.

Having said that, no app will be completely secure, and communicating between apps has its own problems. How does one app verify the other? etc. You can create a web service that would communicate with the database (and communicate with the web service using HTTP or WCF) which would mean your app wouldn't have direct access to the database, but that would only protect the database from your app, it would still allow someone to inspect your app and use the web service, impersonating your app. Also, you would need to host the web service on some web hosting service, and then you would have to trust that service to not inspect your app...

You can reduce the problem by storing the password etc. as byte arrays, but regardless of what you do, I don't know of a way to completely safeguard your app. If a malicious app/actor is on your computer they can inspect your app.

As for your question itself - look into [WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/getting-started-tutorial) or [named pipes (includes a simple example)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-anonymous-pipes-for-local-interprocess-communication).